# Javascript conflict between onmousedown and onmousemove

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, onmousedown, onmousemove

I have developed a volume controller in pure JavaScript. The mouse move works fine but unfortunately I am unable to make it a perfect volume controller.
There are two issues facing on the function:

1. Volume not changing on mouse click
2. `onmousemove` function keep on working even after `onmouseup`

   ```
    var vControl = document.getElementById("voumecontrol");
    var vNow = document.getElementById("volumenow");
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
    vControl.onmousedown = function (e) {
        vControl.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var varPosition = e.pageY - vControl.offsetTop;
            var volPercentage = varPosition / vControl.offsetHeight;
            kili = Math.abs((e.pageY - (vControl.offsetTop + vControl.offsetHeight)) / vControl.offsetHeight);
            var volumePer = kili * 100;
            vNow.style.height = volumePer + "%";
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "volume position " + volumePer + "%";
        }
        vControl.onmouseup = function (e) {
            vControl.onmousemove = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kpcvJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Volume is not changing on mouse click, because the function to be executed `onmousemove` will only get executed when you move the mouse after clicking.
2. You should set `onmousemove` to `null` inside `onmouseup`

Here's the fixed version:

```
var vControl = document.getElementById("voumecontrol");
var vNow = document.getElementById("volumenow");
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
var mousemovemethod = function (e) {
    var varPosition = e.pageY - vControl.offsetTop;
    var volPercentage = varPosition / vControl.offsetHeight;
    kili = Math.abs((e.pageY - (vControl.offsetTop + vControl.offsetHeight)) / vControl.offsetHeight);
    var volumePer = kili * 100;
    vNow.style.height = volumePer + "%";
    resultDiv.innerHTML = "volume position " + volumePer + "%";
}
vControl.onmousedown = function (e) {
    mousemovemethod(e);
    vControl.onmousemove = mousemovemethod;
    vControl.onmouseup = function (e) {
        vControl.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

**Updated Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iHaBe